# Unable to change add to cart button using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, woocommerce

I am calling product list on click of `category button`

as follow :

```
$id = $_GET['ServiceId'];
?>
<ul class="products">
    <?php
        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'product_cat' => $id, 'orderby' => 'rand' );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?>
            <div>
            <li class="food_menu">
                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $loop->post->ID ) ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr($loop->post->post_title ? $loop->post->post_title : $loop->post->ID); ?>">

                        <?php woocommerce_show_product_sale_flash( $post, $product ); ?>

                        <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID )) echo get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog'); else echo '<img src="'.woocommerce_placeholder_img_src().'" alt="Placeholder" />'; ?>
                  <div class="heading_food">
                   <h3 class="food_head"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                    <p class="food_head1">Description 1</p>
                   <p class="food_head1">Description 2</p>
                  </div>
               <div class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></div>
               <div class="qty1" style="width:100%;margin-top:60px">
                 <?php woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart( $loop->post, $product ); ?>
               </div>

           </li>
                </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

It shows me the list of product of that category, It shows a `Add to cart` button, I want is that if anyone click on this button then it should cahnge to `added to cart` and `add to cart` button should be disabled. How can I do this ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this code.I hope, Its will help you..

**HTML:**

```
<input type="submit" value="Add to cart" class="add_cart">
```

**Script:**

```
jQuery('.add_cart').on('click', function () {
    jQuery(this).prop('disabled', true); // for disabled button
    jQuery(this).val('Added to cart'); // for change button as Added to cart
}
```

Thank You!!